# Okay to demand Javascript?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, w3c-validation

I know from an historical perspective that it has always been frowned upon to not gracefully degrade when a visitor with Javascript disabled visits a site but how relevant is this now?

I'm asking since an application I'm building is going to make heavy use of Javascript for charting and user interaction with the charts.

Most of the most popular sites on the web are rendered more or less useless without it enabled.  I can't even login to twitter without it enabled, core bits of Facebook stop working and trying to visit Google maps just redirects to their search home page.

The kind of interaction I'm planning would be next to impossible to do any other way, and even if there was a way there isn't the resources to develop two versions of things.

The problem I have is that the site also needs to be as accessible as possible.  It's an inherently visual site which makes this problematic to say the least.  I'm not even sure there is a solution to this particular problem.  If it's visual it's not going to be suitable for blind people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends entirely on your needs and what *you* want your demographic to be. A lot of sites use exclusively flash to silverlight; does that make them poorly designed? No. All it means is that the site caters to a very specific audience.

As long as you are accepting that there may be a (albeit) small populous that aren't going to use the site (or can't due to missing support) then it's fine.

Side-note: there are other means of conveying graphics other than javascript. Using server-side image generators is one way. You may also decide to use flash/silverlight plugins or activeX/applets. My advice would be to design the site as *you* see fit.

I would bet that the amount of javascript support these days is in the *majority*, so creating the site first then working on the discrepancies later wouldn't be a bad avenue. Youre still going to receive a high saturation of visitors just on the assumption that most clients support it.

Heck, look at sites using html5--it's not a standard, and no browser *has* to support it, but this still doesn't stop people from taking advantage of `article`, `header` & `footer` elements. Granted, there is html5shiv to gracefully down-grade it, but even that depends on JS being present.

Comment: Exactly, this is all part of the motivation for asking the SO community.  Javascript is now so embedded in the web I have been merrily stuffing it in.  According to some sites JS is present in some form on about 92% of the web ... that's pretty standard all in all ...

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has become so thoroughly integrated with web development that it is now users that browse *without* Javascript that have become a novelty.

What you should do is put up a friendly message that informs the user that the specific service your page provides (charts etc.) cannot be provided without JS enabled, and leave it at that.

What I *would* worry about is thoroughly detecting feature compatibility, because while people with JS disabled aren't that common, people with ancient browsers are.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this with [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility), I will cover that perspective. As others have said, Javascript is part of something that we live with. While it isn't expected that the application can be made fully accessible to people with visual imparments, you have to keep in mind other disabilities as well such as mobility imparments. WebAIM has an [article about what to keep in mind when you are coding JS events](http://webaim.org/techniques/javascript/eventhandlers) to make it as accessible as possible.

Depending on what these charts do, you should put the resulting data in an [accessible table](http://webaim.org/techniques/tables/) at the very least either somewhere on the page or a link to the data/table in proxcimity of the graph, so that it is easy to find for those who need it.

You didn't specify who you are making this for, so I will give some more information. Gez Lemon wrote an [article about not using `<noscript>`](http://juicystudio.com/article/say-no-to-noscript.php), his summary is:

> I'm surprised that the noscript element is conforming in HTML5, as there are much better techniques for ensuring that pages work with or without JavaScript. Despite early accessibility advice advocating use of the noscript element, best practice is to use unobtrusive JavaScript for progressive enhancement, rather than relying on fallback content.

This sort of echoes what I began my answer with. However, if you are doing this for a US or state government agency, you must still use `<noscript>` tags because it is a requirement of Section 508. The information with the `<noscript>` tags should be useful. EX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Do something cool
</script>
<noscript>
 Please perform your search again using the <a>javascript-free form</a> 
 to get the results in a table.
</noscript>
```

Comment: Interesting stuff, thanks Ryan.  One of the issues I have is that the problem stems from the input of user data being heavily javascript and also visual.  As you say, getting the data back out and using a table rather than a graph certainly makes sense for output, I guess I'm going to have to think on this some more.

Comment: +1 As usual, Ryan posts good a11y info. Take this with a shaker of salt as most WebAIM readers are probably at the head of the tech curve, but the [latest survey](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey4/#javascript) shows that 98% of the readers have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: @Jammer can expand on what you mean by input? Do you mean by user data input will be visual because the chart will automatically update? If so, you should make the table do the same. Thanks Steve.